# On the plane, what exactly is Lucy doing with her computers?

Tags: lucy

In *Lucy*, when the titular character is on the plane, she does something with her two laptop computers, typing with both hands.

What exactly are those things she wrote? Is this an existing (real life) way of programming? If it is, what is the type of that shell and the whole thing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The events were slightly clearer in the film's original screenplay. In short, she's entering all of the advanced scientific information she's gathered:

> Lucy is engrossed in the thousands of items of coded information scrolling past her eyes. It's illegible [sic] for any normal human being.
>
> **FLIGHT ATTENDANT:** *Miss?*
>
> **LUCY:** (riveted to the screen): *You should wipe your nose.*
>
> The Flight Attendant doesn't understand.
>
> A drop of blood appears in one nostril.
>
> The woman touches her nose and realizes she's bleeding.
>   Slightly flustered, she scurries away. Lucy keeps working.
>
> Up ahead, in the galley, the Flight Attendant talks animatedly to her co-workers. Points toward Lucy. The CABIN MANAGER decides to take matters in hand and comes over.
>
> **CABIN MANAGER:** (politely) *Miss, you really need to shut down your computers now.*
>
> Lucy puts her finger to her mouth, hushing him.
>
> On her screens, Lucy finally reaches the end of the coded signs, gives a little satisfied sigh and gently closes both laptops.
>
> **LUCY** (big smile): ***Twenty-five centuries of knowledge in eleven hours. I couldn't go any faster.***

Comment: wow so she was typing 25000 years of knowledge into two laptops? Wouldn't they have run out of space or something?

Comment: @barry - E=MC2 represents nearly 2000+ years of maths and science. I guess her knowledge would be similarly concise.

Comment: well yeah after all she was compiling it to give it to a scientist and not a common man.

Comment: Well, if humans had been given a few books worth of knowledge of transistors, combustion engines, atoms, antibiotics, vaccines, mathematics, manufacturing etc. to anyone even 1000 years back, we would have been 1000 years in future now. What I mean to say that humans were able to understand all the current advancements many 1000s of years ago, it just took a lot of time for humans to invent it on their own. Any guidance would have accelerated the process a lot faster.